# try to reset edge developer tools

Tags: microsoft-edge, developer-tools

by mistake I emulated other device edge developer tool display

[image]

How can I reset default browser devveloper tool display

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reset the dev tools to restore the default in Edge, just follow the steps below:

1. Open Edge and press `F12` to open the dev tools
2. Press `F1` to open the settings panel when focus in dev tools
3. Scroll the Preference tab to the bottom
4. Click the option `Restore default and refresh`

Just like this:

[image]